# How exactly mem cache and Ehcahe stores data in server?

Tags: java, spring

In Java spring, How exactly mem cache and Ehcahe stores data in server memory?A simple explanation or comparison would be helpful.

Comment: It's really not important how they store data into memory. If you really would like to know, read the source code.

Comment: @Bart Ehcache and memcache store data in very different ways.  It is important to understand their storage model if you want to use them effectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find the internal workings of a caching framework is to go through its source code. I could not find any authoritative article detailing the internal working of these frameworks. Here are few points which differentiates Ehcache from Memcache.

- Distributed caches like MemCache and EHcache work like a **Giant Hashmap**. By Distributed, it means that the cache can be spread over multiple servers, virtually extending the storage capability to unlimited number of objects.
- Although, both Ehcaceh and Memcached appear like a hashmap, the way they work is quite different.
- Ehcache is general purpose **Java Object** cache, meaning generally used with the Java Application to cache java objects. Its generally used as an add-on to the application for caching requirements.
- Ehcache is completely written in Java so its a pure Java application.
- Ehcache offers **RESTful** APIs as an interface.
- Memcached is a general purpose cache for caching **any type of objects**.
- Its a client-server based scheme. So you have a memcached server which holds the actual data and there are clients (available in almost all the languages). The Memcached Server is written in native language(C/C++).
- For using with Java, it needs a memcached client ([spymemcached](https://code.google.com/p/spymemcached/))

I know I have not answered your core question regarding the internal working of the cache frameworks but the points I mentioned should help you select one over other based on your requirements.